# How to prevent duplicate data between different windows?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signalr, indexeddb

I am developing an angular application that communicate with a `websocket` to transmit and receive real time updates.

In my application the user can open multiple windows that are just opened from the main window (the new opened windows are just for displaying details about some data in the main page)

Each opened window needs to receive the same real time updates coming from the `websocket` to the main window, the number of opened windows can be more that 10 sometimes.

The problem is if I opened a new websocket in each new window then started listing to the changes in that window does it cost a lot of network resources? by that I mean that now the client will suffered from internet loss if he opened a lot of new windows..

One solution was proposed by my team is to open one websocket connection from the main page and then use `Indexeddb` to store the changes, and now in all the opened windows will listen to those changes, So I tried the solution but now i am facing some lock issues when trying to access the `Indexeddb`.

So the question is does really opening many new `websockets` connections can cause loss in the network? and is there any other way to share the real time data across different tabs?

Comment: If each new tab is supposed to act as a stand-alone application, I'd probably recommend using `sessionStorage` as the data would be exclusive to the respective tab. If the tabs are supposed to utilize shared data however, then `localStorage` would be the go-to solution as it isn't bound to a given tab and could be used by all instances of your app. However, due to size limitations you'd probably want a reactive backend (ie. API endpoint) each tab could subscribe to and receive the latest updates that way.

Answer (score 1):

> I am dealing with real time updates and in the first page I am starting the connection and when changes are received on the first page i want to share them with the new opened window

For dealing with real-time data, it is best to use MessageQueue mechanic (like `RabbitMQ`). So that your app can listen and know when an object is modified => then update.
And you should also have a database and a backend app that will communicate with the database. If you know `python`, you can try `Flask`

`localStorage` is supposed to be used to contain a string that works like a config variable, not a whole object which will be modified rapidly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,  yes I am using websockets for real time updates (C# with SignalR) , but to eliminate the multiple connections from one client to the server we are trying to centralize the source of data in one page and if other pages are opened they will get notify from the main page

Comment: I was searching and found that there are `webSQL` storage that can be use, but  i don't know if it can be scalable and can be used to sync real time data

Comment: If, as you said, each new Chrome window is a different application, then how can you distinguish which is main page and which is not?
And for instance, let say I open chrome window A, then I open chrome window B. Then I close A, and then open new window C. In that case window B supposed to be main page?

Comment: @Kardon63 I still think that it's not a good idea to use webSQL for real-time data, because it would take lots of resource read/writing.

Comment: only the main page can open new windows, the opened windows are for read only

Comment: yea, me to I am not convinced with the idea of  `webSQL` that's why I am asking is it is a good idea

Comment: it seems that from your comments, the new opened pages are a different application?

Comment: each new window is a different angular application

Comment: If the opened window is a totally different app, then ngrx-store won't work. The only way is for them to share the same database. Because you can't just send datas from one application to other application by localStorage ...

Comment: okk then i will try to use what is available (`webSQL`)

Comment: @Kardon63 okay but as I said, if your objects are going to be written/read continuously, you should go with messagequeue

Answer (score 0):

There are multiples solutions for that but in your case

**First Solution:** I will suggest you to store your object in a database before opening the window, and add all the query params to get this data back in the new windows:

ex:

[www.origin.com](http://www.origin.com) => save your object with a put/patch

=> openning a new Window = [www.origin-popup.com?userId=xxxxx&articleId=xxx](http://www.origin-popup.com?userId=xxxxx&articleId=xxx)

Then in your new angular app, you can retrieve data using a get with your user Id and article Id

**Second Solution:**

You can combine ngrx and ngrx-store-localstorage to use a store and put it to local storage (for 100 objects, will suggest you the first solution)

**Third Solution**

It is still the same angular app, so you can deal with state management and NGRX then, so then in your second windows you subscribe on change to the state, and when you update the state in the first windows, it will trigger change to the second windows : ngrx.io/guide/store

Comment: thanks for the replay, but in my case I am dealing with real time updates and in the first page I am starting the connection and when changes are received on the first page i want to share them with the new opened window

Comment: so the data is always changing

Comment: I see, but it is still the same angular app, so you can deal with state management and NGRX then, so then in your second windows you subscribe on change to the state, and when you update the state in the first windows, it will trigger change to the second windows : https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Comment: does the state persist from one window to another? because the second window is bootstrapping and I can't access values defined in Page A from Page B (assuming page B is opened from page A)